# Dynamically search list of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs in the following structure -

**Html**

```
<div class="firstDiv">
   <input type="text" id="searcher" placeholder="Search names (start typing)">
   <div class="secondDiv">
      <div class="entryDiv">
         <input id="colin">
      </div>
      <div class="entryDiv">
         <input id="chris">
      </div>
      <div class="entryDiv">
         <input id="zander">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#searcher").on("keyup click input", function () {
if (this.value.length > 0) {
  $(".secondDiv entryDiv").hide().filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#searcher").val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
  }).show();
}
else {
  $(".secondDiv entryDiv").hide();
}
});

});
```

What I have tried to do is use a search box - `searcher` using jquery so that on keypress the `entryDiv`s are dynamically shown or hidden based on the `id="colin"` values of the inputs depending on what is typed. So if a user types in the letter "c" the two divs containing "colin" and "chris" would be left present however "zander" would be removed. If the search box was empty then the list defaults back to original view.

Much like the example shown [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_lists_filter_placeholder)

Comment: Can you provide your jQuery code ?

Comment: The example has a completely different structure to your HTML, it uses a single input and shows/hides specific `li`'s based on the entry, you appear to have an input field in each `entryDiv`.

Comment: yes the input field id's are what has to be searched against

Comment: So where are we typing?

Comment: added the search box and js.

Comment: You couldn't drive your solution from the example shown... why?

Comment: None of your inputs are *containing "colin" and "chris"* - they have an *id* of `colin` or `chris`. Should they be `<input value="colin">`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your question specifies

> So if a user types in the letter "c" the two divs containing "colin" and "chris" would be left present however "zander" would be removed

None of your inputs *contain* anything, they have id's. Perhaps what you wanted is, for example

```
<input value="colin">
```

Which will make the fields *contain* that text.

Next, your selectors are missing a period:

```
$(".secondDiv entryDiv")....
```

should be

```
$(".secondDiv .entryDiv")....
```

Finally, here is a working sample

```js
$("#searcher").on("keyup click input", function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.length) {
        $(".secondDiv .entryDiv").hide().filter(function () {
            return $('input',this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        }).show();
    }
    else {
        $(".secondDiv .entryDiv").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstDiv">
   <input type="text" id="searcher" placeholder="Search names (start typing)">
   <div class="secondDiv">
      <div class="entryDiv">
         <input value="colin">
      </div>
      <div class="entryDiv">
         <input value="chris">
      </div>
      <div class="entryDiv">
         <input value="zander">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: excellent works a treat +1 ps will rememeber to add full code next time

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle for people who prefer it: https://jsfiddle.net/ke28daac/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mc5q4efz/2/

Simplified :

```
$("#searcher").on("keyup", function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val();
    if (input.length > 0){
        $('div.entryDiv > input').hide();
        $( "input[id*="+input+"]" ).show();
    }else{
        $('div.entryDiv > input').show();
    }
});
```